# Looking for a message bus for HTTP load sharing

Tags: http, load-balancing, middleware

I have an HTTP application with standalone workers that perform well. The issue is that some times they need to purge and rebuild their caches, so they stop responding for up to 30 seconds.

I have looked into a number of load balancers, but none of them seem to address this issue. I have tried Perlbal and some Apache modules (like fcgid) and they happily send requests to workers that are busy rebuilding their cache.

So my take is this: isn't there some kind of message bus solution where all http requests are queued up, leaving it up to the workers to process messages when they are able to?

Or - alternatively - a load balancer that can take into account that the workers are some times unable to respond.

**Added later:** I am aware that a strategy could be that the workers could use a management protocol to inform the load balancer when they are busy, but that solution seems kludgy and I worry that there will be some edge cases that results in spurious errors.

Comment: Actually I have just found the Mongrel2 project which promises something much like what I describe above, but I am somewhat put off by the fact that their latest version (1.8) seems to be unstable (see their issue #148) and that their master branch haven't been updated for 6 months.

Comment: You may want to consider changing your cache strategy and use a self-evicting LRU or something. If a purge/rebuild is causing you to drop everything for 30 seconds, something is very wrong with the way you're using it.

Comment: @Kylar: I agree that 30 seconds is too long time, but as of now, that part is very hard to change.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Amazon Web Services Load Balancer you can achieve your desired result. You can mark an EC2 Instance behind an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) as unhealthy while it does this cache purge and rebuild.

What I would do is create an additional endpoint for each instance, that is called `rebuild_cache` for example. So if you have 5 instances behind your ELB, you can make a script to hit each individual instance (not through the load balancer) on that `rebuild_cache` endpoint. This endpoint would do 3 things:

1. Mark the instance as unhealthy. The load balancer will realize it's unhealthy after a failed health check (the timing and threshold of health checks are configurable from AWS Web Console).
2. Run your cache purge and rebuild
3. Mark the instance as healthy. The load balancer will run a health check on the instance and only start sending it traffic once it has been healthy for the required amount of healthy health checks (again, this threshold is defined through ELB Health configuration)

Comment: I'll let the bounty system award you half the bounty. The reason that I'm not awarding the whole bounty is that you aren't really pointing to any messaging technologies that fit the requirements that the question states. But that aside, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this definitely went into the "alternatively" section of your post. I thought I would provide input since I have this exact set up and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

I see two strategies here: put a worker offline for the period, so a balancer will abandon it; inverse control - workers pull for tasks from a balancer, instead of the balancer pushes tasks to workers. Second strategy easy to do with a Message Queue.

Comment: The first strategy doesn't seem to work because the balancers will try passing requests to workers - even when they are offline. Maybe the balancer will be fast to abandon the worker, but even if the timeout is just a few seconds, it would be a significant (read: unacceptable) delay.

The bus solution should work. The bounty is given to anyone who can point me in the direction of existing, working technologies that does this.

Comment: @mzedeler Balancers allow to maintain lists of workers, so just deregister a worker before the cache rebuild.

Comment: Thats what I have decided to do for now, but it smells like bad design, since I have to deal with some race conditions that are very hard to mitigate completely due to the environment, I am using (single threaded with an event loop that I am not in control of).

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Hope its okay that I am not rewarding you with the bounty, since the requirement to list specific technologies hasn't been met.

Comment: @mzedeler Of course, I don't feel I've helped you with the answer.